# WPF DocumentViewer Print Landscape Content Cut Off

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

I'm using DocumentViewer in a WPF XAML project. I create a fixed document with the following code. The page looks fine in the viewer. When I print it, it prints in landscape view, but the top 1-2 cm is cut off! I tried it without the scale transform on the dockpanel but that had no effect.

```
    private void PrintReport()
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
        pd.PrintTicket = pd.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;            
        pd.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        pd.PrintDocument(docViewer.Document.DocumentPaginator, "DaySheet");
    }

    public void BuildReport(DockPanel dpPrint)
    {
        try
        {
            // init
            ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);
            dpPrint.RenderTransform = st;

            Size pgSize = new Size(96 * 11.69, 96 * 8.27);
            FixedDocument fd = new FixedDocument();
            
            // add page content
            FixedPage fp = new FixedPage();
            fp.Width = pgSize.Width;
            fp.Height = pgSize.Height;
            fp.Children.Add(dpPrint);

            // set page content
            PageContent pc = new PageContent();
            pc.Child = fp;
            fd.Pages.Add(pc);

            // set up fresh XpsDocument
            var uri = new Uri("pack://daysheet_report.xps");
            PackageStore.RemovePackage(uri);
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            PackageStore.AddPackage(uri, package);
            var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.NotCompressed, uri.AbsoluteUri);

            // write FixedDocument to the XpsDocument
            var docWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
            docWriter.Write(fd);

            // display XpsDocument in DocumentViewer
            docViewer.Document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            docViewer.Document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = pgSize;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are probably using the default Microsoft PS driver instead of the vendor specific driver.  Looks like you are sending directly to the printer instead of using the print driver which would use the vendor driver instead of Microsoft Driver.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your feedback, but it's a bit confusing. I have a printer driver installed for my printer. whether I click the Print icon in the DocumentViewer or run the code above, both result in cutting off the top part. what would I need to do to fix this???

Comment: Then that means it is not the c# code and probably the driver that needs to be updated.  There are also two types of print drivers 1)PCL 2) PS.  You may be using the wrong one.  You may be using a Network Printer that has a Print Que that on Network is PCL and you are sending PS.  Long time ago I got my MIS people to either Name the Network Queues with PCL or PS.  Even in some cases install both.  We were getting all different combinations of issues.  Since some applications only supported one type, and the local machine drivers and the Network Queue did not match in the type.

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing around with printer drivers but it seemed to make no difference. The printer driver I have installed is the correct one for my laser printer and the right version for Windows 10 64-bit. When I print from Word, Excel, PDF its all fine, but from my WPF app it crops the top part of the page content.

As is so often the case, I got around the problem with a hack. I just changed the page content to use a StackPanel and I placed a blank TextBlock as the first child to push the other content down.